# Sphinx and re-usable Django apps

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx

## Problem

While trying to generate sphinx documentation for a re-usable Django application I struck upon the following snafoo. When sphinx parses the `model.py` code it is thwarted by the code therein trying to access the Django *project* settings. As this is a standalone/reusable *application* there is not a primary *project* providing these settings i.e. there is no `ROOT/PROJECT/PROJECT/settings.py` file.

## Setup

In the interest of clarity here is what I've done. Traverse to what would be the usual *project* folder `cd ROOT/PROJECT` and create an *application* `django-admin startapp APPLICATION` which produces the following structure

```
/ROOT/
  /PROJECT/
    /APPLICATION/ 
      admin.py
      apps.py
      models.py
      tests.py
      views.py
```

**Note** : There are no `/ROOT/PROJECT/PROJECT/*.py` files because I did not navigate to the *root* folder `cd root` and create a *project* using `django-admin createproject` as one normally might.

Next one creates the sphinx documentation `spinx-quickstart docs` producing the following additional structure.

```
/ROOT/
  /PROJECT/
    /docs/
      /source/ 
        ...
        conf.py
      make.bat
```

That is the docs are built next to the `APPLICATION`.

## Question

What do I place within `conf.py` to properly load the *application* without there being a `settings.py` file ?

## Homework

In trying to resolve this I have perused a number of SO Questions, Blogs and the Django Docs and not found a succinct solution. As this has been asked a few times before on SO I'd like to motivate that it not be closed as a duplicate, if the answer in the proposed duplicate uses one of these snippets as it's solution.

- Fails with `AppRegistryNotReady`

  ```
  from django.conf import settings
  settings.configure()
  ```
- Similar to the first method of failure i.e. emits `AppRegistryNotReady`

  ```
  from django.conf import settings
  settings.configure()
  settings.INSTALLED_APPS += ['fintech']
  ```
- Fails with `ImproperlyConfigured`

  ```
  import django
  django.setup()
  ```
- There is a really old solution mentioning the deprecated `setup_environ`

  ```
  from django.core.management import setup_environ
  from django.conf import settings
  settings.configure()
  setup_environ(settings)
  ```
- This is also a favourite answer but fails if there is no `settings.py` file.

  ```
  import django
  os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'PROJECT.settings'
  django.setup()
  ```

I've also made this question rather verbose as the related questions on SO are rather terse and not especially helpful. If it's any help I'm using Django 1.10.

## Update

I have since found that if one imports their `setup` function from `setuptools` versus `distutils.core` that one may invoke the setup script to compile their documentation as in `python setup.py build_sphinx -b BUILDER` It's probably best to re-ask this when invoking `setup.py` over `docs/conf.py` via either the `make.bat` or the `MakeFile` provided by Sphinx.

I suspect the outcome would be similar though, namely include the provided answers within `docs/conf.py` or alternatively within `setup.py`, both must be called within the same Python session after all.

Comment: "I've also made this question rather verbose..." -- No, you included relevant details and showed that you put effort into solving the problem.

Comment: I have seen several reusable Django apps having their own `settings.py`. If your app expect some global settings, I think you should define them (as default values) in app related settings.

Comment: @albar for me, the issue was that my app wasn't importing any settings directly from `settings.py`, but Sphinx couldn't load the `models.py` module to read the docstrings because it imports `django.db.models` and that throws: `Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.`

Comment: It would seem that the real answer is to invoke both `settings.configure()` and `django.setup()` from any script that is loaded prior to the loading of a `models.py` module. Django per se does not seem to care where one does this. Thanks all for your time and contributions. I tried contributing back in the update, If I must elaborate on this let me know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want to make your documentation dependent on a "demo" project, then you can manually build the settings in your `conf.py`. In the path setup section:

```
import django
from django.conf import settings
import os
import sys

# add path to sys.path (this might be different in your project)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))

# pass settings into configure
settings.configure(
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'my_reusable_app',
        'any_other_dependencies',
    ]
)

# call django.setup to load installed apps and other stuff
django.setup()

# ... continue with rest of conf.py
```

Now Sphinx can import the app modules without having a project `settings.py`. Other settings can be passed to `settings.configure()`.

Comment: This is a pretty common pattern found in a lot of django projects and also comes very handy when configuring custom settings for testing reusable apps.

Comment: I've mark yours as the correct answer. I'm not sure if the bounty is returned in this case. Thanks for the answer (and thanks for the loan).

Comment: @Carel I'm not worried about the bounty, but I'm happy you asked the question because apparently it motivated me to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 4):

It's not an answer to the question

> What do I place within `conf.py` to properly load the *application* without there being a `settings.py` file ?

but an alternative approach: **Put a minimal, viable Django project in the reusable package**. It can be used for implementation examples, testing (including code coverage), development and doc generation. We do it that way in our company's private repositories and I have seen a few django packages on github that do it too.

A typical structure of my packages looks like this:

```
docs
├── conf.py
├── ... rst files
mypackage          # the actual package
mypackage_demo     # the Django project
├── .coveragerc
├── manage.py
├── settings.py
README.rst
requirements.txt
setup.py
```

In `docs/conf.py` I check for a settings environment variable and use the demo project if non is given:

```
if not os.environ.get('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'):
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mypackage_demo.settings'
django.setup()
```

That way you could build the docs using another project by setting the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable before calling `sphinx`.

`settings.py` just contains the minimal configuration necessary to run the application. The absolute minimum for Django to work are these:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = ''
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'mypackage'
]
```

Comment: This appears to be common practice and is what I adopted after asking the initial question. Maxime Deuse's answer is also in line with this one. I'll leave the accepted answer as Greg's but ask that people upvote rather then downvote these alternate answers it's nice to have a pre-configured demonstration setup for Django packages.

Comment: I'll be honest: I really don't like this answer, because it requires a project with a `settings.py` and the *entire point of the question* is to use Sphinx with a re-usable app without a `settings.py` file. That being said, I think the advice to include a demo project and use it for Sphinx isn't bad, so if no better answer shows up, I'll reluctantly award the bounty to you.

Answer (score 1):

I did have the same issue with Django 1.11 and Sphinx 1.5.5. I did not manage to get it working properly and all the solutions you mentioned above did not work either. In the end I solved it by adding this to my Sphinx conf.py:

```
import sys, os

project_path = os.path.abspath('.')
# For Django to know where to find stuff.
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_project.settings")
sys.path.append(project_path)

# For settings.py to load.
os.chdir(project_path)

# For the models to load.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: This requires a project named "my_project" and for that project to have a `settings.py` module. When documenting a re-usable app, I would like to not have a project associated with it.